# Slow query when using very common value in where clause

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have some flights (~3 mill) and some aggregated flights (~15 mill), and now I want the flights that do not exist in aggregated_flights.

Now, I'm wondering how to get the best performance on this query:

```
select 
  f.id 
from 
  flights f left join 
  aggregated_flights af on af.flight_id = f.id 
where 
  af.flight_id is null and 
  f.status = 'COMMITED' 
;
```

If I leave out the status-clause, the query is very fast, but when I include it, the query takes 1-2 minutes.

The value in the status column is 'COMMITED' for ~99% of the flights

I've created a partial index like this:

```
create index on flights (id) where status = 'COMMITED';
```

But it seems to have no effect - the query is still very slow.

What's the recommendation here?

(Experienced in Postgresql 9.4 and 9.6)

Table definition:

```
app=> \d flights
                                          Table "public.flights"
        Column        |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
----------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id                   | integer                     | not null default nextval('flights_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                 | character varying           | 
 aircraft_id          | integer                     | 
 status               | character varying           | 
 departure_airport_id | integer                     | 
 arrival_airport_id   | integer                     | 
 departure_time       | timestamp without time zone | 
 off_block            | timestamp without time zone | 
 arrival_time         | timestamp without time zone | 
 on_block             | timestamp without time zone | 
 radiation_amount     | numeric(10,6)               | 
 total_day_minutes    | integer                     | 
 total_night_minutes  | integer                     | 
 total_instr_minutes  | integer                     | 
 approach_type_id     | integer                     | 
 note                 | character varying           | 
 created_at           | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at           | timestamp without time zone | 
 flight_type_id       | integer                     | 
 owner_id             | integer                     | 
 night_landing        | boolean                     | 
 load_filename        | character varying           | 
 recalc               | boolean                     | 
Indexes:
    "flights_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "flights_id_idx" btree (id) WHERE status::text = 'COMMITED'::text
    "index_flights_combined" btree (name, departure_airport_id, off_block)
    "index_flights_on_aircraft_id" btree (aircraft_id)
    "index_flights_on_approach_type_id" btree (approach_type_id)
    "index_flights_on_arrival_airport_id" btree (arrival_airport_id)
    "index_flights_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "index_flights_on_departure_airport_id" btree (departure_airport_id)
    "index_flights_on_flight_type_id" btree (flight_type_id)
    "index_flights_on_off_block" btree (off_block)
    "index_flights_on_on_block" btree (on_block)
    "index_flights_on_owner_id" btree (owner_id)
```

Autovacuum:

```
app=> show autovacuum;
 autovacuum 
------------
 on
(1 row)
```

Analyze:

```
app=> analyze verbose flights;
INFO:  analyzing "public.flights"
INFO:  "flights": scanned 30000 of 80606 pages, containing 1161009 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 3122535 estimated total rows
ANALYZE
```

Explain output:

```
app=> explain (analyze, buffers) select f.id from flights f left join aggregated_flights af on af.flight_id = f.id where af.flight_id is null and f.status = 'COMMITED' limit 100;

Limit  (cost=7.25..68.59 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=58744.490..58744.604 rows=100 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=367361 read=248982
  ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=7.25..1829081.46 rows=2981880 width=4) (actual time=58744.489..58744.586 rows=100 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (f.id = af.flight_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=367361 read=248982
        ->  Index Scan using flights_id_idx on flights f  (cost=0.43..743949.15 rows=3106090 width=4) (actual time=0.066..24170.693 rows=3106983 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=316162 read=85698
        ->  Index Only Scan using index_aggregated_flights_on_flight_id_and_flight_relation_id on aggregated_flights af  (cost=0.56..886207.11 rows=15357503 width=4) (actual time=0.014..31282.777 rows=15360252 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
              Buffers: shared hit=51199 read=163284
Planning time: 246.341 ms
Execution time: 58744.695 ms
```

**Update** I added an index on the `aggregated_flights` table, just on the flight_id. This definately made the query faster, but I still think that 10 sec is a bit much.

```
app=> explain (analyze, buffers) select f.id from flights f left join aggregated_flights af on af.flight_id = f.id where af.flight_id is null and f.status = 'COMMITED' limit 1000;
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=3.83..453.80 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=9986.052..9986.508 rows=470 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=365265 read=126777
   ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=3.83..1341784.78 rows=2981880 width=4) (actual time=9986.050..9986.437 rows=470 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (f.id = af.flight_id)
         Buffers: shared hit=365265 read=126777
         ->  Index Scan using flights_id_idx on flights f  (cost=0.43..743949.15 rows=3106090 width=4) (actual time=0.935..3891.800 rows=3107353 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=317084 read=84797
         ->  Index Only Scan using aggregated_flights_flight_id_idx on aggregated_flights af  (cost=0.43..398876.22 rows=15360252 width=4) (actual time=0.023..3270.955 rows=15360252 loops=1)
               Heap Fetches: 0
               Buffers: shared hit=48181 read=41980
 Planning time: 53.676 ms
 Execution time: 9986.603 ms
(12 rows)
```

Comment: Could your provide the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE for both queries?

Comment: @Eelke yes, of course - added it to question

Comment: That's a simple `explain` output, the information provided by `explain (analyze, buffers)` would be more helpful

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, ok, I was not aware of that. Added as requested.

Comment: Did you swap queries with the explain results? Because now it looks like your query **with** the status clause is much faster in both cases. (Assuming I'm interpreting _execution time_ correct)

Comment: @zwippie Not sure - maybe I made a mistake when updating the question. It should be correct now :)

Answer (score 1):

With the two indexes on the join columns, one of them partial to accommodate the `WHERE` condition, you have improved query speed as much as is possible.

The only improvement on the PostgreSQL side would be an *index only scan* on the partial index. For that, you should `VACUUM flights` and use PostgreSQL 9.6 or above, where index only scans on partial indexes are supported.

Beyond that, the best optimization is to give the machine enough RAM to cache the whole database (or at least the involved indexes) so that no data have to be read from disk. You can use [`pg_prewarm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgprewarm.html) to load tables or indexes into the cache.

Comment: maybe I made a mistake when updating the question. It should be correct now. Also checked the autovacuum setting and ran an analyze. Is it clearer now?

Comment: That doesn't look right. I don't see the condition `f.status = 'COMMITED'` in the execution plan.

Comment: you are right, but that is the output I get. It does use the index 'flights_id_idx' though - which is the partial index I created, so I guess it is being applied.

Comment: I just noticed that the join may be using a "wrong" index - the one called 'index_aggregated_flights_on_flight_id_and_flight_relation_id'. I will dig into that

Comment: **Update**: Created an index just for `flight_id` on `aggregated_flights`. Now the query is using that, and reduced query time to ~10 sec. Still a bit much, I reckon...?

Comment: thanks, I don't have access to 9.6 in my production environment, but I'll see if pg_prewarm will make it speedier, as I do have plenty of RAM available.